# Cartthrob Issue/Error - Adding to cart gives "Not in Stock"

Tags: cartthrob

Carthrob 4.6.2 - EE5

When I add an item to the cart I get the error "XXX is currently out of stock" This happens on my own custom inventory channel. It doesn't happen with the installed examples setup on initial CT installation. All channel fields are mapped to the CT ones.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the field you have specified for "Product Inventory" which you can find in **Add-On Manager / CartThrob Pro Configuration / Products** - it is the fifth field down in a channel definition block there.  If this field is set in your custom channel, check to see what kind of field this is set to be (should be a regular text field), and what values it has.  If this field is, or appears to have value 0 then you'll get stock out errors...

Another place to check is the option in  **Add-On Manager / CartThrob Pro Configuration / Orders** for "Update Product Inventory When Editing Order" - if you do not want inventory warnings at all, simply de-select this option.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, will check this out. I have question though - I have 600+ entries and have  just added this field (I had assumed this was for the Item Reference Number so have changed this) so obviously all are now '0'. Is there any way of bypassing this? Or do I have to assign a value to each of the 600+?

I have other fields with a higher than zero number in so I could possibly assign one of those but my concern would be whether this number would be changed or reduced dynamically as it needs to be set at what it is in each case.

Comment: Not clear from what you say quite what you are doing, but if there is some other field that has the stock level in it that is different from the one assigned, can you not just change the assigned field to that one instead?  Otherwise, I guess you could update the appropriate field values using direct SQL manipulation (make sure you work on a copy of the SQL in case of errors!).  Entering 600 values manually would be quite tedious I guess.  HTH